# xlsxwriter equivalent code in openpyxl for conditional formatting

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have been trying to convert the below code to openpyxl. Have been trying to figure out for the past couple of days.

Snippet:

```
april_final0.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='BDM')
enter code here`workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['BDM']
#Reference http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format
#format = workbook.add_format()
#format.set_bold()
#format.set_font_color('red')
format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'bg_color': 'red'})
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'bg_color': 'yellow'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'bg_color': 'green'})
#worksheet.conditional_format('G2:G33', {'type': '3_color_scale'})
worksheet.conditional_format('G2:G233', {'type':     'cell',
                                'criteria': '<',
                                'value':     88,
                                'format':  format})
worksheet.conditional_format('G2:G233', {'type':     'cell',
                                'criteria': '<=',
                                'value':     92.4,
                                'format':  format1})
worksheet.conditional_format('G2:G233', {'type':     'cell',
                                'criteria': '>=',
                                'value':     92.5,
                                'format':  format2})
writer.save()
```

Could someone help me to convert this snipped to openpyxl (I am looking forward to convert because though in excel it is evident, but excel doesn't interpret it as  a background color which gives me some issues while I am trying to merge this generated excel with formatting)

Comment: What don't you understand about openpyxl's conditional formatting?

Comment: @Charlie Clark : I tied to apply conditional formatting in openpyxl as well. I am able to see the background colour of the cell visually, but excel doesn't recognise it as a background colour and I am not able to change it through excel or when I tried to copy multiple conditional formatted excel sheets and merge into one - I just get the cell value and not the formatting. I am observing the same issue in xlsxwriter as well. Am I missing something ? Please suggest

Comment: Is the question about openpyxl or xlsxwriter. The code is for xlsxwriter.

Comment: Read the relavent Documentation: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/formatting.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @stovfl

Comment: @CharlieClark: The question is on xlsxwriter and openpyxl. I am able to apply formatting through the code, but while I try to edit the formatting through excel, I am not able to though it is visible !

Note: I have written the equivalent code in openpyxl and tried !